# How to double space the \thanks footnote?

Tags: footnotes, titles, line-spacing

The journal I intend to submit my paper to requires all the text, including footnotes and acknowledgments, be double spaced. I use the setspace package and put `\doublespacing` and `\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing}` in the preamble. Everything works well except for the fact that the \thanks footnotes are not double spaced. How can I solve this?

An mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\doublespacing\normalsize}

\title{How to double space the ``thanks'' footnote?\thanks{\normalsize Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.}}
\author{John Smith\thanks{\normalsize Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.}}
\date{\today}

\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\maketitle

\lipsum[3]

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{titlepage}

\section{Introduction}

Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random text.\footnote{\lipsum[5]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: since you talk about `\footnotelayout`, i assume you're using footmisc, but there's no guessing what class you're using.  an mwe would be useful.  having said all of which, `\thanks` isn't "quite" a `\footnote`, and it may be that all you need do is `\thanks{\doublespacing <blah>}`

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I'm using footmisc and the article class. Unfortunately, \thanks{\doublespacing ...} produces an error. I'll provide an mwe shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\thanks{\protect\doublespacing\normalsize ...}`.

Alternatively, since typing all that is tiresome, use the [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch the code for the `\thanks` command itself; thus

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thanks}{#1}{\protect\doublespacing\normalsize#1}{}{}
```

Subsequently, `\thanks{whatever}` should produce a normalsize, double spaced footnote.

Comment: Thanks! \normalsize\protect\doublespacing doesn't work perfectly (i.e. \normalsize no longer works), but \protect\doublespacing\normalsize is just perfect!

Comment: @tymon: Thanks for accepting Ian's answer; don't forget to upvote it as well!

Comment: @tymon --- I didn't notice the problem with `\normalsize`; I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @doncherry --- done!