# Changing spacing for \thanks generates empty line

Tags: footnotes, titles, line-spacing

In a double-spaced article, I'm trying to keep the `\thanks` note single-spaced. I use [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61395/how-to-double-space-the-thanks-footnote) to change the spacing of `\thanks` back to single-spacing. This works, but it also generates an empty line at the start of the note. How do I get the text to start on the same line as the <sup>*</sup> symbol?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{-4cm}Title goes here}
\author{Author Goes Here\thanks{\protect\singlespacing\protect\lipsum[1]}}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\noindent \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{First section}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I achieve single spacing *without* the use of `\protect\singlespacing` in `\thanks`.

Comment: You're right. It must be one of the other packages I'm loading in the actual file that causes the odd behaviour. Let me search for that.

Comment: Footnotes shouldn't be double spaced, when using `setspace`. You can do `\protect\linespread{1}\protect\selectfont` instead of `\protect\singlespacing`.

Answer (score 2):

My initial MWE was too minimal. The problem turns out to be the order of loading packages. Specifically, loading `\usepackage{setspace}` after `\usepackage{hyperref}` creates a double-spaced thanks-note. Trying to correct that by adding `\protect\singlespacing` to the thanks-note generates the white line in the thanks-note.

Loading `\usepackage{setspace}` before `\usepackage{hyperref}` keeps the thanks-note single-spaced.

Alternatively, Egreg's solution to add `\protect\linespread{1}\protect\selectfont` to the thanks-note works regardless of the order of loading packages.

For completeness, the full preamble of the actual document is as follows.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[left=1in,top=1.5in,bottom=1.5in,right=1in,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[disable,section]{easy-todo}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}

%% Swap the next two packages to correct the double-spaced thanks-note
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[font=normalsize]{subfig} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}                 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}                  

\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xtab} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 

\AtBeginEnvironment{xtabular}{\singlespacing} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{abstract}{\onehalfspacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{-4cm}\textsc{Title goes here}}

\author{Author \textsc{Goes Here}\thanks{\protect\lipsum[1]}} 

\date{\vspace{1.5em}\today}
\maketitle


 \begin{abstract}
 \noindent \lipsum[2]
 \end{abstract}

\clearpage
\section{First section}
\noindent \lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded as late as possible; only a few package should be loaded after it, notably `cleveref`. You're definitely loading it too early.

Comment: There's no point in loading `color` as well as `xcolor`.